# Angular, form validation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am developing an angular application with a form  in an html table, which has a button to delete a row in the table and a button to add a new row. When I press the button save only the information fill in the last row is saved in the database How to save the information fill in all the rows of the table?

here is my  typescript and html  code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { EdtService} from '../_services/edt.service';





interface Enseignant {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;


  constructor( private edtService:  EdtService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  public TabArray: Array<any> = [];
  
  public edt: any = { };

  addFieldValue() {
      this.TabArray.push(this.edt);
      this.edt = {};
  }

  deleteFieldValue(index:any) {
      this.TabArray.splice(index, 1);
  }

   enseignants:Enseignant[] = [
      {value: 'Andry', viewValue: 'Andry'},
      {value: 'Manoa', viewValue: 'Manoa'},
      {value: 'Christiano', viewValue: 'Christiano'}
    ];
  
   
    saveEDT(): void {
      const data = {
      enseignantname: this.edt.enseignantname,
      heure1: this.edt.heure1,
      heure2: this.edt.heure2,
      heure3: this.edt.heure3,
      heure4: this.edt.heure4

      };
  
      this.edtService.createEdt(data)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.submitted = true;
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
    
}
```

```html
<table class="table  table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Enseignant</th>
          <th>07h15-09h15</th>
          <th>09h15-11h15</th>
          <th>12h30-14h00</th>
          <th>14h00-15h30</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let field of TabArray; let i = index">
          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-select [(ngModel)]="field.enseignantname" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                  {{food.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input [(ngModel)]="field.heure1" matInput type="text" name="{{field.heure1}}" />
              </mat-form-field>
              
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input [(ngModel)]="field.heure2" matInput type="text" name="{{field.heure2}}" />
              </mat-form-field>
              
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                 <input [(ngModel)]="field.heure3" matInput type="text" name="{{field.heure3}}" />
              </mat-form-field>
           
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input [(ngModel)]="field.heure4" matInput type="text" name="{{field.heure4}}" />
              </mat-form-field>
            
          </td>
         
          <td>
              
              <button mat-icon-button class="deletebutton" color="warn" type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">
                 <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-select  id="formEnseignant" [(ngModel)]="edt.enseignantname" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="let enseignant of enseignants" [value]="enseignant.value">
                  {{food.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text" id="formHeure1" [(ngModel)]="edt.heure1" name="Heure1" />
              </mat-form-field>
              
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text" id="formHeure2" [(ngModel)]="edt.heure2" name="Heure2" />
              </mat-form-field>
              
          </td>
          <td>
             <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text" id="formHeure3" [(ngModel)]="edt.heure3" name="Heure3" />
             </mat-form-field>
           
          </td>
          <td>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text" id="formHeure4" [(ngModel)]="edt.heure4" name="Heure4" />
              </mat-form-field>
            
          </td>
          <td>
              <button mat-icon-button class="addbutton" color="primary"type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">
                 <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary"class="enregistrer" (click)="saveEDT()">
  <mat-icon>done_outline</mat-icon>
</button>
<p *ngIf="submitted">Requete executée avec succès</p>
```

Comment: in the html code it is "let enseignant of enseignants" [value] = "enseignant.value" " but not "let food of foods" [value]="food.value"

Comment: in html code it is "{{enseignant.value}}" but not {{food.value}}

Comment: Wrap table with form and create `ngForm` ref on it and pass it through on submit. `<form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit($event, addForm)" >` Now in `onFormSubmit` you should get all ngModel values using `secondParam.getRawValues()`

Comment: ok thanks i will try